# Immutable class with attribute build-up

Tags: python, oop, immutability

I have a class `DifferentialExtension`:

```
class DifferentialExtension(object):
    __slots__ = ('f', 'x', 'D', 'T')
    def __init__(self, f=None, x=None):
        /*
        # some code that builds up list 'self.D'
        */
        self.D = tuple(self.D)
        return None
```

I am to make the class "Immutable" i.e. objects created using the `DifferentialExtension` shouldn't be allowed to change attribute "D" (after `__init__` has finished), neither those attributes be assigned to a new object. It is not necessary for `D` to be a `list`, it can be a `tuple` when returned finally.

```
In [1]: DE = DifferentialExtension(log(x), x)
In [2]: DE.D
Out[2]: ((Poly(1, x, domain='ZZ'), Poly(1/x, t0, domain='ZZ(x)'))
In [3]: DE.D = (1, 5, 5)  # raises Error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in Python, you have to assume that whoever uses your class is not trying to do something vicious. Thus if he *really* wants to change the value of `D` he probably has good reasons. Therefore, you probably don't want to make it impossible to change `D`, as that is rather un-pythonic. However, you might want to help the user to not accidentally change `D`. That is best done with a read-only property, as:

```
class DifferentialExtension(object):
    def __init__(self, f=None, x=None):
        self._D = 'immutable value'
        return None

    @property
    def D(self):
        return self._D
```

Running this gives:

```
>>> d = DifferentialExtension()
>>> d.D = 'mutate'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

If the user *really* wants to change the value, he can, by directly accessing `self._D` but then you have to assume he knows what he is doing, since he is messing with one of your internal, underscored variables.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 class DifferentialExtension(object):
     _frozen = set()
     __slots__ = ('f', 'x', 'D', 'T')
     def __init__(self, f=None, x=None):
         self.D = 'something'
         self.D = tuple(self.D)
         self._frozen.add(id(self))

     def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
         if id(self) in self._frozen:
            raise TypeError('object is frozen')
         object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

**Testing**:

```
In [29]: a = DifferentialExtension('eh', 'oh')

In [30]: a.D
Out[30]: ('s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g')

In [31]: a.D = 'something else'
...
TypeError: object is frozen
```

Edit. 
As mentioned in another answer, a namedtuple is the natural way to do this, but since you are doing some computation during construction, use a *classmethod* as an alternate constructor:

```
class DifferentialExtension(namedtuple('DifferentialExtension', 'f, x, D, T')):
    @classmethod
    def build_me(cls, f=None, x=None):
        # a bunch of code that works on D and sets D and T (if you need T)
        T = 'something T'
        D = 'something' ##D = tuple(D) works
        return cls(f, x, D, T)
```

**Testing namedtuple**:

```
In [41]: DE = DifferentialExtension.build_me(f='some f value', x='some x value')

In [42]: DE.D
Out[42]: 'something'

In [43]: DE.D = 'some other thing'
...

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `namedtuple` as your basis for an immutable object. You may extent them to suit your needs if you wish.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class DifferentialExtension(namedtuple('DifferentialExtension', 'f x')):
    def another_method(self):
        print self.x

x = DifferentialExtension(1, 2)

x.f = 2.2
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```